# MAUI: WHere are the Nuget Packages referenced?

Tags: xamarin, maui

I am currently trying to migrate an app from xamarin to maui.

I want to take all the nuget packages I had on my xamarin project and "copy" them over to my maui project.

Inside my xamarin.csproj file, I can see the itemgroup with all the packages referenced.

This is what it looks like in xamarin:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="MarcTron.Admob" />
    <None Remove="ShapeControl.Forms" />
    <None Remove="ImageCropper.Forms" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AsyncEnumerator" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="CarouselView.FormsPlugin" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie" Version="4.0.10" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

I copied this whole codeblock over into the new csproj file in hopes that it would find the packages, but it doesnt. THey all come out red in vs

Is there more to it then just copying the item groups?

Comment: did you restore the packages?  If you create a new MAUI project the `PackageReference` looks the same as what you have posted

Comment: Ok, it seems one isse was that I had to many white spaces (eg: enter) in between the two item groups. it can only ever have one white space...

Answer (score 0):

> I copied this whole codeblock over into the new csproj file in hopes that it would find the packages, but it doesnt. THey all come out red in vs

Because some packages (eg: `CarouselView.FormsPlugin` and `Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie`) are only available for Forms not MAUI. You should check that each package is available for MAUI.

For `CarouselView.FormsPlugin`, [MAUI already has this control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/). Then `Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie`, you can see this [Pull Requests](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin/pull/379). It said the current progress for MAUI. `AsyncEnumerator` is available for MAUI.

I hope this helps.